# Yii2 403 forbidden during ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, controller, yii2, http-status-code-403

I had jquery in `order/my-cart` and I tried to get the data from `order/delivery-verify`. My javascript is as follows

```
$('form#Confirm').submit(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();

        Core.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "/order/delivery-verify",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    if (typeof (result.status) != 'undefined') {
                        if (result.status == 200) {
                            window.location.href = '/order/checkout';
                        } else {
                            Core.handleInvalidServerResponse(result);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    })
```

This script is working fine in `subdomain.example.com` but throws 403 error in another server `subdomain.example-one.com`

*EDIT*
OrderController.php

```
<?php
namespace frontend\controllers;

use common\components\CErrorAction;
use common\helpers\Com;
use frontend\components\CController;
use frontend\models\User;
use yii;
use frontend\models\Configuration;
use yii\helpers\Json;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use frontend\models\Order;
use common\helpers\Mailer;

use frontend\models\NewsletterSubscriber;
/**
 * Class SiteController
 * @package frontend\controllers
 */
class OrderController extends CController
{

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => CErrorAction::class
            ],
        ];
    }

   /**
     *
     * @return type Json
     * @Title("Checkout verify")
     */
    public function actionDeliveryVerify()
    {
    .....
    }
......
}
```

Comment: Check the permissions of that particular path on second server. Make sure the controller action `delivery-verify` is accessible.

Comment: @HarishST I cant able to get response from any action on OrderController

Comment: Do you have `behaviors()` method in your controller ?

Comment: Check this Doc: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-filters-accesscontrol

Comment: @HarishST no behaviour methods in OrderController

Comment: @HarishST Is it mandatory for behaviour function in controller?. I dont have that function in some of the other controller in subdomain.example-one.com. That all are works fine.

Comment: It is not mandatory to have `behaviors()` method. Can you mention which `Class` you are extending for defining the `OrderController()`. It would be nice if you can post the code snippet, so that we can understand the issue better. By the way, default behaviors() will be used from the parent class if you haven't explicitly override it in your `OrderController`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213760/discussion-between-droiddev-and-harish-st).

Comment: Can you add the code of `frontend\components\CController` to the question? Your `OrderController` extends it so the reason might be there.

Answer (score 0):

```php
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array(
          'allow',
          'actions'=>array('delivery-verify'),
          'users'=>array('*'),
        )
    );
}
```

Try adding `accessRules()` in your controller. The above code allows any users to access `delivery-verify` action.

Please follow the below links for official Yii1.1 API documentation:
- [Yii1.1 CController](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#accessRules-detail)
- [Yii1.1 CAccessControlFilter](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CAccessControlFilter)
- [Authentication and Authorization](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth)

Comment: Same error 403 Forbidden. I am confused it is working in one server and not in another.

Comment: May be check the permissions of the file.

Comment: 0644 is the permission

Comment: What about other Controller File Permissions? 
Try changing the permission and check whether that works.

Comment: All files are 0644. OK will change and check .

Comment: @HarishST they are not using Yii 1.x. The classes prefixed with `C` are not from framework.

Comment: @MichalHynčica This one happen in different server only. it is working in localhost, subdomain.example.com